# how to determine event signers(cancel,declined ......) when a signer finish signing envelope in Docusign api

Tags: jakarta-ee, docusignapi

I am using Embedded Signing with the DocuSign api, but I want to know how to determine what action the  recipient took (i.e. they signed, declined to sign, viewed, etc).  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There will be a URL parameter contained in the return URL once they are down with the signing session, even if they close the window.  The url parameter that gets returned is in the form

```
?event=action
```

where *action* is one of the following:

- cancel (recipient cancels signing)
- decline (recipient declines signing)
- exception (exception occurs)
- fax_pending (recipient has fax pending)
- id_check_faild (recipient failed an ID check)
- session_timeout (session times out)
- signing_complete (recipient completes signing)
- ttl_complete (the TTL expires)
- viewing_complete (recipient completes viewing the envelope)

For instance, if you host an embedded signing and your return URL is set to www.google.com and the recipient signs the envelope, they will be redirected using the URL

```
www.google.com?event=signing_complete
```

Then all you need to do is parse that event off of the url and use that to determine what the recipient did.